# Capturing RadioButton click and taking action

Tags: jquery

I have 3 radiobutton on my page. There are 3 buttons also on the same page. i want to show different buttons when each is clicked.

```
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />
<input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />
```

Update: There is only one button to be shown corresponding to each radio button..For eg: If Radio1 is clicked show Button 1, if Radio 2 is clicked show Button 2 and so on

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() { // at dom ready
  $('input.abc').change(function() { // on radio's change event
    $('.buttons-to-hide-class').hide(); // hide buttons
    $('#button-to-show-id').show(); // show desired button
  });
});
```

Comment: There is only one button to be shown corresponding to each radio button..For eg: If Radio1 is clicked show Button 1, if Radio 2 is clicked show Button 2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Radio1').click(function() { $('#button1').value = 'new value'; });
```

something like that

Comment: I think this is the answer the OP is actually looking for; instead of creating 3 buttons, create 1 and change the action based on the radio button selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Nicky De Maeyer is suggesting is better, and I'm sure there is a better way to code this way, but:

**Script**

```
$(function() {
    //hide all the buttons when the page loads
    $('.def').hide(); 
    //add an onchange function to each radiobutton
    $('input.abc').change(function() { 
        //hide all the other buttons
        $('.def').hide(); 
        //construct the ID of the button to show and show it
        $('#' + this.id + '-Button').show()
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />
<input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="grp1" class="abc" />

<input id="Radio1-Button" type="button" value="1" class="def" ></input>
<input id="Radio2-Button" type="button" value="2" class="def" ></input>
<input id="Radio3-Button" type="button" value="3" class="def" ></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying

```
Click()
```

or maybe

```
change()
```

should work :)